# How to create a bot for a real-time PvP game using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, game

Unfortunately, I am not well-versed in machine learning. However, I'm trying to understand if it's possible to create a bot for a real-time PvP game like, for example, Clash Royale or Random Dice: Wars. Can you please advise if the current state of open-source technologies allows for this? What tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bot for real-time PvP games raises ethical concerns and is often against the terms of service of the game. Using bots to automate gameplay can provide unfair advantages and is generally considered cheating. Game developers invest a lot of effort in creating fair and enjoyable experiences for players, and the use of bots can undermine these efforts.

It's essential to respect the terms of service of the games you play and avoid engaging in activities that may result in penalties, including the suspension or banning of your account.

If you are interested in exploring machine learning or AI in a gaming context, I would encourage you to focus on projects that align with ethical considerations and contribute positively to the gaming community. This could involve creating AI opponents for single-player modes or developing tools that enhance the gaming experience without providing unfair advantages.

Comment: Your response is not an answer. Please write a comment.

Comment: As for your opinion, you are looking at the task too narrowly. Bots of this kind can be used by game developers themselves, for example, for testing or assisting in match-making.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bot that can play a game and learn to get better at it through reinforcement learning.  This is actually a pretty common thing people do to play around with AI.  It looks like pytorch even offers a "Teach an RL Agent to Play Mario" tutorial as part of their docs.  I'd say run through a few tutorials like this one and then it's just a matter of adapting to PvP by having your bot play itself and other people.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/mario_rl_tutorial.html